# Is boto slow for large files?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I'm doing a few performance tests for uploading large files, on the order to 100MB+.  I've read postings about breaking things up and uploading pieces in parallel, but I'm just trying to figure out how fast a large file can go.

When I do my upload and watch the performance with collectl, second-by-second, I'm never getting over 5MB/sec.  On the other hand if I reduce the filesize to just 50MB I can do uploads at 20MB/sec.

Is there some magic going on that's based on filesize?  is there a way to make my single 100MB file upload faster? What would happen if it were 500MB or even 5G?

hmm, I tried it a number of times and consistently got 5MB/sec and now when I tried it again I got over 15.  Is this because I'm sharing bandwidth?

-mark

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely not any magic going on in boto that would account for the variability you are observing.  There are so many variables in this equation, e.g. your own connection to the internet, your provider's connection to the backbone, overall network traffic, the load on S3, etc. that it is extremely difficult to get a definitive answer.

In general, I have found that I can achieve the best performance by using multipart upload and some sort of concurrency.  The `s3put` command line utility in boto provides an example of one way to do this.  Also, if your S3 bucket is located in a specific region you might see better performance if you connect to that particular endpoint rather than the generic S3 endpoint.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm connecting from an amazon instance and so my comment about shared bandwidth